# Prevent &amp; from showing up html

Tags: html, encoding

On my html document for some reason instead of printing what it's suppose to be, it's just displaying

```
&amp;
```

encoding is utf-8

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You  might get an answer if you post a sample of the code.

Comment: About the best answer you're going to get with that question is "you're doing something wrong". You're going to have to be more specific. Try to come up with the smallest possible HTML file that exhibits the problem, then edit your question to include that. Otherwise we're all just guessing.

Comment: sorry guys, I posted it without the code tags so it just showed up as & and not what I wanted. Fixed now.

Comment: Please post the code or part of the code where you are having this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the entity code for a ampersand - which is why it's actually displaying as &. Just add amp to the end to actually show it.

```
&amp;amp;
```

Which will '&amp;' in an HTML document.

Comment: i thought the question was the inverse.  that is,  i think the issue may be doubke encoding the output.

Comment: Yeah, I believe it is the inverse. This answer is only applicable to the original question, not sure about the new one.

Comment: ha, this was for the wrong thing I asked but it actually came in very useful :D Thanks guys i got it figured out.